# What does 'view' container do in XML of Android

Tags: android, xml, view

In this XML what is advantage of using *view*?

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout android:id="@+id/coordinatorLayout2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:id="@+id/constraintLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <View
                android:id="@+id/view"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="720dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/toggleBtn"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="72dp"
                android:text="@string/toggle_screen"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textTv"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="120dp"
                android:text="@string/primary_screen"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/toggleBtn"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/toggleBtn"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/toggleBtn" />

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

I tested the code with and without *view* and I didn't see any difference in its output on device. Generally what is usage of *view* in XML? Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think in this code, view application is clear:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        app:tabGravity="fill"
        app:tabMode="fixed" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="#c6c4c4" />

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

When view is in xml output will be:

[image]

But without view in xml output will be:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

According to your layout, I've just updated your layout added colour to see the view, below is the layout and image.

Here is your layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout android:id="@+id/coordinatorLayout2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/constraintLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <View
            android:id="@+id/view"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="720dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            android:background="@color/black_2"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/toggleBtn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="72dp"
            android:text="this is button"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textTv"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="120dp"
            android:text="this is text view"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/toggleBtn"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/toggleBtn"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/toggleBtn" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**Image with view**

[image: Image with view]

So, if you have **view**, because of the height of `ConstraintLayout` is **720dp** the **ConstraintLayout** will stretch to maximum because of ***wrap_content*** behaviour.

**Height of Constraint Layout with View**

[image: Height of Constraint Layout]

And if you remove **view**, then the height of **ConstraintLayout** also changes

**Height of Constraint Layout without  View**

[image: Height of Constraint Layout without View]

> It depends on your requirement, you need to have **View** or not, but
>   currently it has no impact.

Comment: Thanks for answer @Waqar UlHaq, but my question is this, if view has no effect in our output, what is its rule? When it will be useful?

Comment: I've mentioned in my answer, **it depends on your design requirement whether you need it or not, but currently it has no impact.**

Comment: it will be good may be when you want to add some paddings/margins and want to set some elements at the bottom.

Comment: Please add a code which view has useful application in it.

Comment: I always use **view** as a divider to divide some sections or in recycler view

Comment: Hi, May you delete your answer? Because I want to delete my question but Stack doesn't permit me. It's cause is that my question is answered