# Why is there a need for programatically creating views?

Tags: android, android-layout

My whole android development cycle has been creating XML files for layouts. Now that I am in an internship , they require me to build views programatically. like creating new Linearlayout , setting params , adding it to contentview , adding other child widgets and completely skipping the XML part.

This is kind of what it looks like :

```
    LinearLayout parent = new LinearLayout(requireContext());
    parent .setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    parent .setLayoutParams(getParams(0, 0));

    Button button= new Button(requireContext());
    button.setLayoutParams(getParams(1, 0));
    button.setText(string(R.string.date));
    //button.setPadding(20,20,20,20);
    button.setBackground(drawable(R.drawable.button));
```

Complicated layouts are tricky to build with XML itself let alone code.

What is the advantage of this ?
Is it doing something that XMLs can't achieve ?
Am I missing out by not learning how to code layouts programatically ?

Comment: See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60521248/

Comment: Sounds like they just like not having preview capabilities, lol. Oh well, if that's what they say you should do, I guess that's what you'll have to do.

Comment: It's probably sliiiightly faster, but not meaningfully so.  Certainly not worth the cost of having to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case it can fully be replaced with XML. Yes, with xml it will be easier to read and to edit layouts, but in some cases your custom views should have custom behaviour (e. g. you can override onMeasure and do something every time measuring is occurred). But even doing custom views you can inflate it using XML and doing rest with the code. So the best solution will be to use XML if it is easy and possible. In the future maybe Jetpack Compose will be recommended way to build layouts (now it is still in development).